# html5 video crashes in Chrome and Opera but works fine in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video

It's 5:30AM and I'm stuck with this video problem.

I had it all working before, and now, it has problems...
I try to change encoding, but it's still not good... Worst part is that it works when it's runned from local file, but won't from server ( I add file types in htaccess )...

Here is the ffmpeg encoding:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -bt 50k -b 250k -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -acodec libfaac  "upload/' .$newName. '.mp4"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -bt 50k -b 250k -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm "upload/' .$newName. '.webm"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -bt 50k -b 250k -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -aq 100 "upload/' .$newName. '.ogv"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -bt 50k -b 250k -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -aq 100 "upload/' .$newName. '.ogg"');
```

or:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" "upload/' .$newName. '.mp4"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm  -aq 100 "upload/' .$newName. '.webm"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -aq 100 "upload/' .$newName. '.ogv"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -aq 100 "upload/' .$newName. '.ogg"');
```

or:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" "upload/' .$newName. '.mp4"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" "upload/' .$newName. '.webm"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" "upload/' .$newName. '.ogv"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "' .$tmpName. '" "upload/' .$newName. '.ogg"');
```

Nothing create good enough file to play in Chrome...

URL of file(s):

```
http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/9b8a0c1a5af65c92936e3c6806181ec3.ogv
http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/9b8a0c1a5af65c92936e3c6806181ec3.ogg
http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/9b8a0c1a5af65c92936e3c6806181ec3.webm
http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/f41355af09218d660a5d78a4012a7177.mp4
```

Video element:

```
<video poster="http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/images/xxx.jpg" >
<source src="http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/xxx.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/xxx.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" />
<source src="http://urthots.com/homepage/upload/xxx.ogg" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" />
</video>
```

What can cause this?
I tried everything, encoding changing, HTML element changing, htaccess changing, I tried with videos from other sites, and they are working okay...
I have no idea what is problem...

Can someone please help...

Comment: The question title implies the browser crashes - is this actually true?

Comment: Did you find the solution to your question? I have probably a similar problem.

Comment: could you put your source at jsfiddle ? thats maybe can make clear your actual problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a codecs issue from the server side. You need to serve each browser with a particulary video format and codecs. Hope this can help you out: http://html5video.org/